# Postman works but Fetch doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working my way through the ScotchIO tutorial for Express, Node & Mongoose - and i can't seem to get `req.body` to come through.

If i make the request in Postman, it works fine - i can see the record update on Mlab:-

[image: postman body]

[image: postman headers]

But if i make a `fetch()` POST request in chrome (testing there until i can get it working, then i'll move to a React Native app), i get a series of `ValidationError: User validation failed` (User is my Schema, then it gets more specific with things like `ValidatorError: Path`userName`is required.` etc).

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: {
        userName: 'IngleburtHumperdink',
        email: "Ingle@Humber.com",
        password: "mypw_blah"
    }
})
```

my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

UPDATED:  server.js

[image: server.js]

Comment: Can you include the actual response that Postman receives?

Comment: You are sending json in `fetch` body, not `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Just setting `Content-Type` header doesn't magically convert it  - you need to do it manually. Or set content-type to `application/json`.

Comment: Also, is there a difference if you use double quotes around `userName` in the `fetch`? You use single quotes around the other two items, and there is no error with them...

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex and @223seneca - 
223seneca - it receives `res.json({ message: 'user created!' })` as in the code. I can't see anything else on postman that might be of interest. The content-type in response headers seems to be content-type application/json though.

Alex - in my app.js i'm using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`. Going from a tutorial so not totally sure how those two work together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I missed off the `body: JSON.stringify({ userName:'myUserName' })`.

So you were right @AlexBlex in that i was sending JSON, just needed json.stringify() to convert it.

Tested and fixed. Many thanks both!